# Git flow: как синхронизировать несколько feature веток?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

Пытаемся внедрить у себя [git-flow](/questions/tagged/git-flow). Вопрос в том как правильно синхронизировать `feature/...` ветки между собой.

Пример:
Разработчик 1 начал работу над `feature/test1`, разработчик 2 начал работу над `feature/test2`

Допустим что `feature/test2` зависит от `feature/test1`, и в нее периодически нужно заливать новый код из `feature/test1`

Как правильно это делать и подразумевает ли нечто подобное `git-flow`, или это в корне не соответствует идеологии `git-flow`?

Comment: - Зависящие друг от друга feature branches — это однозначный bad smell, поскольку любой чейнджсет, внесенный в `feature/test1,` может влиять на поведение продукта в `feature/test2`.

- **Не делайте так.**

- Лучше перепланируйте вашу текущую итерацию таким образом, чтобы у вас не было зависимых features. Например, принимайтесь за реализацию `feature/test2` только в тот момент, когда `feature/test1` уже замерджена в [`master / develop.`](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) Или пусть оба разработчика параллельно работают над `feature/test1`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно постоянно делать `rebase` по изменениям в ветке `feature/test1`. Так получится что `feature/test2` будет основан на последних изменениях `feature/test2`.

Comment: Только в таком сценарии надо внимательно следить, чтобы никто не сделал rebase ветки feature/test1.

Answer (score 0):

"как правильно это делать и подразумевает ли нечто подобное git-flow, или это в корне не соответствует идеологии git-flow?"

По какой причине они не могут вместе работать в одной ветке, отдельной от master ?
Если пушить в ветку, только то, что как минимум компилируется а максимум что работает, то проблем быть не должно.